# Pull latitude and longitude out of Extent object

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri

I have successfully created a esri.geometry.Geometry.Extent object through using the draw tool.  In my addToMap function that is the callback on the onDrawEnd event I want to pull out the latitude,longitude of the four corners of the box.  I pulled xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax of the extend with my wkid set at 4326 for the Geometry object.  Based on my limited understanding I assumed that x,y would be in lat long but considering that the value for x is 5550 I don't believe that to be correct.  What did I do wrong or what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You're right, 5550 is not valid.  But 4326 is the code for a WGS-84 Spatial Reference which means that the x,y should be latitude/longitude values.  What do you mean you "set" wkid to 4326?  Did you reproject the extent to that projection before pulling out the x,y values?

Comment: @progrmr In my original code I left everything as the defaults which should be 4326 and never set the spatialReference anywhere.  In another test I tried to set it in my map declaration.  I also did try to set the spatialReference after I got the geometry back into addMap and this did not work as well.  The more I look at it the more I think it must be some sort of bug in the esri javascript.  I am also seeing weird behavior that when I minimize or maximize firebug while on the page every geometry I get returned seems to be in what I would expect, a correct lat and lon.

Comment: What are the wkids of the extent itself (ext.spatialReference.wkid) and the underlying map? I think the map defaults to 102100 (WebMercator), which would make the 5500 more sensible (depending on where in the world you are....England?

Comment: The default depends entirely on which map service you add first to the map. If it's an ArcGIS Online service, that is probably Web Mercator (WKID 102100 or 3857). As @Juffy hints, 5500 in Web Mercator is 5.5 km east of the Prime Meridian.

Comment: In my addToMap function when I output to the console the spatialReference.wkid from the extent coming in it is set to 4326.  Not sure how I can get an x value of 5500 when it seems to be set correctly.

Comment: You can set the spatialReference of the extent to be anything you want, but that doesn't project the extent for you. If you use the draw tool the have the user draw an extent on the map, the extent's real spatial reference will be the same as the spatial reference of the map, which is probably 102100 or 3857. You need to [project the extent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427702/720773) from one of those to 4326 if you want longitude/latitude.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your extent is in the Web Mercator spatial reference. Check your extent object's spatialReference.wkid property. If it is 102100 or 3857, then it is Web Mercator. In that case, converting to geographic coordinates (i.e. longitude and latitude) is very easy, using the [esri.geometry.webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic function](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.geometry.webmercatorutils-amd.html#webmercatortogeographic).

If your extent object is not in a Web Mercator spatial reference, then you must use a [GeometryService](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html) to project the geometry to longitude and latitude (e.g. WGS1984, whose wkid is 4326). The [Project a point sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/util_project.html) shows how this is done.